# iOS jailbreak get object based on class name

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a dylib which has a object of class "mConWifi". I have the main app which loads this dylib and executes following code

```
Class klass = objc_getClass("mConWifi");
SEL sel = sel_getUid("ListAllWifi:");
if ( [klass respondsToSelector:sel] )
    objc_msgSend(klass, sel);
```

When above code is called, object of class mConWifi is already created in Memory.

My objective is to get object based on class name and then invoke a method. With above code I am not able to as respondsToSelector fails. I have already tried "ListAllWifi" and "ListAllWifi:"

Any ideas how to get object of a class based on class name?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please mark an answer as a solution if it solved your problem

Comment: hybridcattt - Thanks for the reply. I will try it and let you know.. just got tied up with something urgent in between...

Comment: There is no hurry. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are trying to test a method of class (which are declared with `+`), but in fact you have an instance method, declared with `-`.

Try this:

```
Class klass = objc_getClass("mConWifi");
SEL sel = sel_getUid("ListAllWifi:");
if ( [klass instancesRespondToSelector:sel] ) {
    id object = [[klass alloc] init];
    objc_msgSend(object, sel);
}
```

Comment: When I use your code without : or just "ListAllWifi", atleast it goes in the if loop.. Now you are creating a new object of klass where as I already have a object in memory, How could I get reference to that? (I can do it by passing pointers etc but I am loading a library which has the object so that stops me... forward declaration with extern doesn't help and gives linker error as its not a static library..)

Comment: There is no built-in way to find all (or any) living instances of a class. But you can do that by yourself, in your class mConWifi declare a class method that will return your existing object, for example +(mConWifi*)getObject {return sharedObject;},  and call mConWifi *livingObj = [klass performSelector:@selector(getObject)];

Comment: Great suggestion - Although I cannot reverse engineer if I am using someone's library but if I have the code, I have a way through. Thanks for clarifying..